# funcion para eliminar columnas falla (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

Hola que tal? tengo una funcion mysql que en un momento funciono, y ahora sin razon aparente falla, y me tira el mismo error siempre, aqui el codigo

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `borrar_columna`(
    IN `nombredecolumna` TEXT ,
    IN `nombredetabla` TEXT)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
IF (SELECT count(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = nombredetabla AND table_schema = DATABASE()) = 1 THEN
SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT('DROP TABLE `', nombredetabla ,'`;');
PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt;
EXECUTE st;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
ELSE
IF (SELECT count(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = nombredecolumna AND table_name = nombredetabla AND table_schema = DATABASE()) = 1 THEN
SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', nombredetabla ,'` DROP COLUMN `', nombredecolumna ,'`;');
PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt;
EXECUTE st;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
END IF;
END IF;
END
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente...

> Error de SQL (1054) la columna '123' en field list es desconocida

el comando que le doy es asi

```
CALL borrar_columna(`123`,`prueba`);
```

Por supuesto la columna y la tabla existen y estan creadas para hacer la prueba. Funciono varias veces, pero ahora falla, no entiendo porque, yo veo todo correctamente, espero por favor que me puedan ayudar. Gracias.

Comment: En la función verifica la existencia primero de la columna, si existe la elimina.

Comment: El error dice que la columna no existe. Si ya se borró una vez, pues dices que ha funcionado anteriormente... ¿cómo quieres que funcione de nuevo si ya borró la columna? ¿O la recreas de nuevo para luego borrarla?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es el tipo de comillas que usas en la llamada:

```
CALL borrar_columna(`123`,`prueba`);
```

Al usar ese tipo de comillas, MySQL piensa que estás refiriéndote a alguna columna de alguna tabla.  Para pasarle cadenas de texto, debes usar las comillas simples, así:

```
CALL borrar_columna('123','prueba');
```

Comment: :S jajajajaj si gracias